# Loop and/or conditional statements produce different values every time it is ran

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I have this loop which reads a file from a folder whose values are then put into a list. This list's contents are then compared to another list wherein an operation will be done based on the existence of the contents in the other list. My problem now exists with the operations being done. The operations sometimes works but most of the time, the results are all sorts of random. It does some of the if and elif statements more than what is required so I'd assume it has something to do with the conditional statements below. As of right now however, I can not figure out why it happens.

```
pair = {}
bag = []
new = []
os.chdir(classPath)              
for file in os.listdir():
    prod = Decimal(1)
    bag2 = []
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = f"{classPath}\{file}"
        input = readFile(file_path)
        for i in list(set(input)):
            bag2.append(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', i))
            for j in list(set(bag2)):
                count1 = Decimal(0)
                op = Decimal(0)
                if j in bag:
                    count1 = Decimal(count1 + 1)
                    op = Decimal(count1 + 2) / ((len(bag)) + (2 * (len(list(set(dict()))) + len(new))))
                    prod = Decimal(prod * op)
                elif j not in bag:
                    op = Decimal(count1 + 2) / ((len(bag)) + (2 * (len(list(set(dict()))) + len(new))))
                    print('hello')
                    prod = Decimal(prod * op)
            pair[file] = prod
```

e.g. file contains word `hello hi`
list 2 contains `yes no`. Since hello and hi do not exist in the other list, the elif statements must be performed twice.

```
def spamCount():
bagInput = []
os.chdir(spamPath)  
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = f"{spamPath}\{file}"
        inputs = readFile(file_path)
        bagInput.append(inputs)

return list(chain(*bagInput))
```

bag list is taken from this function

```
a = spamCount()
    for i in (a):
    bag.append(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', i))
```

Comment: What is it: `(len(list(set(dict())))`?

Comment: ah sorry, forgot to mention that. it's just the length of a list from another function. its value is 7.

Comment: Wait, `len(list(set(dict())))` is **always** 0.

Comment: well unless you have overiden the builtin dict, dict() will give you an empty dict which will give an empty set, an empty list and its lenght will be 0

Comment: You have a condition (if j in the bag ( do something) else if j is not in the bag (do something else). What could be happening is that when it goes to the else part, the data could have two conditions. Where the data is not in the bag and it is also not not in the bag. That can happen if the data is null.  You might try  (if j is not in the bag, ELSE do something)

Comment: Yes, but I even can't thought about overriding built-in `dict`, even despite `input` was overridden.

Comment: Also, where are you adding anything to the bag array? That is probably where you are getting the null variable from where it is not not in the bag also.

Comment: Ive changed the dict() to dictS(), input to inputs, as well as the suggestion by @user1854438 but i still get the same results. Will also be adding how I get the bag array in a bit

Comment: I don't know what op is supposed to do. But can you create two list. One list that contains the values from the other and one list that does not contain the values? You can easily create the list like this    list3 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2] and another for values in the list list4 = [x for x in list1 if x in list2]

Comment: I think ive figured it out haha. the third for loop iterates through the list even if it is not complete yet

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in os.listdir():
    prod = Decimal(1)
    bag2 = []
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = f"{classPath}\{file}"
        inputs = readFile(file_path)
        for i in list(set(inputs)):
            bag2.append(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', i))
        for j in list(set(bag2)):
            print(j)
            count1 = Decimal(0)
            op = Decimal(0)
            if j not in bag:
                op = Decimal(count1 + k) / ((len(bag)) + (k * (len(list(set(dictS()))) + len(new))))
                prod = Decimal(prod * op)
            else:
                count1 = Decimal(count1 + 1)
                op = Decimal(count1 + k) / ((len(bag)) + (k * (len(list(set(dictS()))) + len(new))))
                prod = Decimal(prod * op)
        pair[file] = prod
```

as it turns out, the third for loop in this snippet loops through the list even if it is not complete yet. Having the loop be done after the bag2.append being complete is the fix I made.